# Is Jobatar safe?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, applications, online

The company I've applied for a job, is requesting applicants to use that service to make a pre-interview, it consists in answering some questions, a few of them recording myself.

They have given me a user id to login Jobatar app, but I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8UnTcL8eOg) video on YouTube and from what I've understood Jobatar allows sharing the pre-interview over internet for companies interests. I don't want to be on internet unless it was for a good reason, and this is not. Aside I'm not that person who looks nice in any media.

How can I express my concern to the potential employer so that I get to go through a process that doesn't involve that site?

Comment: What part on the video made you think that? Just watched it and missed it...

Comment: @DarkCygnus from 1:02, did I misunderstood?

Comment: I think that perhaps you did, they don't mention anything regarding sharing your interview with other companies, they just mention that the platform will enable you to comment with other colleagues about candidates (something that I doubt anyone on this site would suggest doing with private recruiting processes, and all the GDPR thingy)

Comment: Hello tec01 and welcome to The Workplace. I've edited your text because the original question is something only you can answer, and therefore not a good fit for this site. If my edit conflicts with your original intent, please feel free to roll back or re-edit.

Comment: Not an answer so I'm adding as a comment. At 1:02 the video says your answers will be shared with _colleagues from around the globe_, I think this implies the employer's colleagues. I didn't see anything in that video that implies your answers will be shared publicly, and that would be a question for that service to clarify.

Comment: @rath I thought so, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are going to share your personal information not only with your prospective employer but a third party web service.**

It is unclear from the video who is going to have access to what information or your video answers and if they are encrypted or not.

If you're uncomfortable with this, don't do it. (my recommendation btw.)

Offer alternatives to answer their questions and step away from the process if they insist on using this service.

Tell them in no uncertain terms that you feel this service to be inappropriate or not safe enough.
If you're inclined to do so, you could also let the jobatar people know about your issues with their service.

Thinking about this, you could also check back with the jobatar service about your concerns and see if they answer to your liking but I'm not convinced that this is a good idea in general if you're cautious about your privacy.

Comment: I had to do it anyway because I was running out of time, but as you said I'm sharing my info with a third party service, so next time I will offer the employer an alternative like Skype.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I trust this service/company ?

The practical answer to this is, **if you want to carry on with this opportunity you have no choice but to trust this platform.**

I watched the video you shared, and **in no part I heard anything related to sharing your application with other companies.**

Perhaps you are confusing it with what they do mention about *sharing the application link* on the company's social media, so candidates can easily access the link and apply.

They also mention that the platform will enable you to "discuss with colleagues across the world" and compare candidates that apply. This, however, I think was just a phrase to make the platform sound "international" or better than it is, as I wouldn't suggest you discuss about company recruiting processes so openly with other colleagues from other companies.

Still, they never explicitly mention anything about sharing your video.

Besides from that, I suggest you **read the terms and services of such platform** so you are completely sure what you are getting into.